# MVC custom view routing based on controller structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need my ASP.NET MVC5 view structure to reflect the structure of my controllers.

---

The controllers of my application have the following structure:

```
Controllers
|--- Main
|    |--- HomeController.cs
|--- User
|    |--- HomeController.cs
|    |--- SettingsController.cs
|--- Admin
|    |--- HomeController.cs
|    |--- ManageController.cs
```

The controller structure is based on the user type, and the `Main` controllers are accessible to all users. My URLs are like this:

- `/Main/Home` (default)
- `/User/Settings`
- `/Admin/Manage/Users`

But as you can see all namespaces have a `HomeController`, but when I want to create, for example, an Index view for `User/HomeController` it will be placed inside `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`. But I actually need this view to be here: `Views/User/Home/Index.cshtml`. Below an example structure of how I need the views to be structured.

```
Views
|--- Main
|    |--- Home
|    |    |--- Index.cshtml
|    |    |--- Contact.cshtml
|--- User
|    |--- Home
|    |    |--- Index.cshtml
|    |--- Settings
|    |    |--- Index.cshtml
|--- Admin
|    |--- Home
|    |    |--- Index.cshtml
|    |--- Manage
|    |    |--- Index.cshtml
|    |    |--- Users.cshtml
```

I tried using a custom `RazorViewEngine` but all examples I could find ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375578/4136777)) wouldn't work for my situation. Is there a way to achieve this specific structure with custom routing?

Comment: areas will be the good solution for you problem. You can get lots of retentive link in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you could use Areas to structure your website (provided you only want 1 level).

If you want multiple levels of controllers (`/section1/sectiona/SomeController.cs`), then have a look at [MvcCodeRouting](https://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I belive you're looking for areas.

Areas was avalable in MVC 4. And there is no difference in MVC 5.

[Here you can find a details](http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify whatever path you need instead of using defaults if areas don't work for you :

```
return View("user/home/index", model);
```