# Error in displaying area's views along pages in Views folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a MVC 5 project with lots of controllers, models and pages. For making them more maintainable i moved some of related files to a new area, called Mail.

The project structure is like:

```
Automation (project's name)
 |- Controllers
 |- Views
 |- Models
 └── Areas  
      └── Mail
          └── Models 
          └── Controllers
               └── MailboxController
          └── Views
               └── Inbox.cshtml
```

I did below steps to be able to load newly moved views:

- Change namespace of the controller in the Area -> Mail -> Controllers
- Add Rout to the MailAreaRegistaration.cs as follow:

  ```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
  {
      context.MapRoute(
          "Mail_default",
          "Mail/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { action = "Inbox", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
          new [] { "Automation.Areas.Mail.Controllers" });
  }
  ```
- RegisterAllAreaas() in the global.asax.cs
- Change MapRout method in the project's RoutConfig file as below:

  ```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Dashboard_Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          namespaces: new [] {"Automation.Controllers"}
      );
  }
  ```

All the pages that are in the main View folder rendered as expected, but when i want to load the inbox.cshtml in the Mail area this errors are shown:

```
The view 'inbox' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Areas/Mail/Views/mailbox/inbox.aspx
~/Areas/Mail/Views/mailbox/inbox.ascx
~/Areas/Mail/Views/Shared/inbox.aspx
~/Areas/Mail/Views/Shared/inbox.ascx
~/Views/mailbox/inbox.aspx
~/Views/mailbox/inbox.ascx
~/Views/Shared/inbox.aspx
~/Views/Shared/inbox.ascx
~/Areas/Mail/Views/mailbox/inbox.cshtml
~/Areas/Mail/Views/mailbox/inbox.vbhtml
~/Areas/Mail/Views/Shared/inbox.cshtml
~/Areas/Mail/Views/Shared/inbox.vbhtml
~/Views/mailbox/inbox.cshtml
~/Views/mailbox/inbox.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/inbox.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/inbox.vbhtml
```

I tested below urls for inbox page, but no one was successful

- http://localhost:port/Mail
- http://localhost:port/Mail/Mailbox
- http://localhost:port/Mail/Mailbox/inbox

How can i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you have `MailboxController` class like this:

```
public class MailboxController : Controller
{
    // default action in area
    public ActionResult Inbox()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

First, create custom class to perform view search in area folders given by example below:

```
namespace Automation
{    
    public class CustomRazorEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomRazorEngine()
        {
            // short note:
            // {2} = area name
            // {1} = controller name
            // {0} = action name
            AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                // add these routes in area scope
                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            };

            ViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                // example routes
                "~/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
            }

            FileExtensions = new[]
            {
                "cshtml"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then I register customized view engine as described above in `Application_Start` method inside Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomRazorEngine()); // customized view search engine
    // other settings here
}
```

With setup above those URLs below should work:

```
http://localhost:port/Mail/Mailbox
http://localhost:port/Mail/Mailbox/Inbox
```

References:

[Custom View Engine with Dynamic View Location](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location)

[ASP.NET MVC Custom View Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322756/asp-net-mvc-custom-view-routing)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to follow the MVC conventions and to move the `Inbox.cshtml` file to the `Areas\Mail\Views\Mailbox\Inbox.cshtml` location that is expected by MVC (you are only missing the `Mailbox` folder).

However, if your intention is to customize the view location to your whim, use [Tetsuya's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392954).