# .NET MVC DisplayModeProvider fallback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, tablet, displaymode

I am currently using `DisplayModeProvider` to check if a mobile request is coming in and serving up a `Page.mobile.cshtml` file if I detect a mobile request otherwise I'm serving the default page `Page.cshtml`. This also works as a fall-back - if there is a mobile request for PageX but `PageX.mobile.cshtml` does not exist but there is a `PageX.cshtml`, I serve `PageX.cshtml`. This is working as intended.

I would like to add to the fall-back behavior as I include support for tablet requests. So when a tablet device request is detected, if I have a `Page.tablet.cshtml`, it will go ahead and serve that file. If there isn't a `...tablet.cshtml` file, I'd like it to try to serve the `Page.mobile.cshtml` file and if a `Page.mobile.cshtml` does not exist, we would serve the `Page.cshtml` file.

Is there a way to do this without having to create a `...tablet.csthml` file for every page and `Html.Partial`'ing a `...mobile.cshtml` within it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing the route preference dynamically. Define the hierarchy as you want like tablet first then mobile and then web pages.

Here is a sample how CustomViewEngine can do that:

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyViewEngine()
        : base()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Views/tab/{1}/%1/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/mobile/{1}/%1/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/%1/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
    };

    PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Views/tab/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/mobile/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
    };
   }
}
```

Here the view will be searched in the `/Views/tab/` folder first then `/Views/mobile/` followed by `/Views/` and the `/Views/Shared/` folders.

Detail of the implementation have been discussed here: [ASP.NET MVC Custom View Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322756/asp-net-mvc-custom-view-routing)